# What fetch_template() really means?

Tags: templates, php, ee3

Could you tell me please, what fetch_template() really means in ExpressionEngine?

Debugger shows me an info like below and not only for ".head" template but for a few more templates.

> 0.0003s
> 1.2MB SELECT `exp_templates`.*, `exp_template_groups`.`group_name` FROM (`exp_templates`) JOIN `exp_template_groups` ON
> `exp_template_groups`.`group_id` = `exp_templates`.`group_id` WHERE
> `exp_template_groups`.`site_id` =  '1' AND
> `exp_templates`.`template_name` =  '.head' AND
> `exp_template_groups`.`group_name` =  'core'
>
> ## system/ee/legacy/libraries/Template.php L:216 EE_Template::fetch_template()

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

**fetch_template** is very important function in ExpressionEngine.

When you browse your EE url in the frontend `i.e., http://example.com/about-us`, it displays the HTML you saved for that template group.

As you know in EE, all the templates are saved in the Database. You can edit the templates from the backend as well as the frontend.

The `fetch_template` function works in following manner.

1. It takes your segments as an argument and triggers the function.
2. It searches the template in the database that matches with arguments that you have passed in URL `i.e., /about-us/`**(about-us)**
3. If a template is found in the database and there is no file found in FTP, it will return the data found in DB row. (We can save files on FTP by backend settings option **Save Templates as Files** in template settings)
4. If a segment is wrong and you have set a 404 page in the backend, it will return data of the 404 row.
5. If there is a file in the FTP folder and the file edit date is not matched from the DB, it will read the FTP file and return the FTP file content.

The final returned content is filtered by removing EE comments and EE tags are then converted to HTML.

I hope that makes sense. :)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, everything is clear.

However, debugger mark it as "attention" ("!" sign at 1,2mb) probably because of this operation uses too much of memory. 1,2mb is not too much I think so why it have been marked?

Thanks.

Comment: Might be because you have lot of templates. It's ok. I don't think you need to worry about this.